# What does "luscious" mean?

Tags: word-meaning

What does "luscious" mean other than "delicious" and "sexually appealing"? 'cause I don't understand neither this sense of the Lexico entry (basically "richly green or lavish"? what does that mean?)

> Richly verdant or opulent

nor this example from the Cambridge dictionary.

> She slipped into her **luscious** pale pink silk pajamas.

And then there are some "luscious voices" from Longman

> Back then, those things which couldn't be said were hinted at in the grain of those **luscious** voices.

I read that part about "pleasing to see, hear, or feel" from the Cambridge dictionary, but it's way too general, and I doubt I can take it literally (suppose I like to listen to heavy metal music, I'm pretty sure it doesn't make it "luscious")

Comment: The origin of ***luscious*** is uncertain, but even if it's not actually derived from ***delicious*** and/or ***lush** ( = **sumptuous**)*, it probably acquires most of its meanings / allusions from those two. Not really the kind of adjective to apply to heavy metal music, no matter *how* much you like it.

Comment: Food is luscious if it is rich, juicy and sweet. Not all delicious food is luscious. The sound of a certain kind of voice, or the sensuous feel of silk clothing, can be _metaphorically_ described as luscious because they evoke the same kind of feeling.

Comment: [3a : richly luxurious or appealing to the senses](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/luscious)

Comment: [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/luscious) shows 5 definitions, including "richly satisfying to the senses or the mind". You could cross-check that dictionary, wiktionary, merriam-webster.